# Firing up errors

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native. I don't comprehend the use of `state`.

I'm wondering how can I fire up the error even if I'm reporting the error to `onBlur()` because I want if a user leaves the input, the error should appear, but nothing happens.

Here's my test case:

**SignUp.js**

```
<TextInput 
  onChangeText={(value) => this.state.mail = value}
  onBlur={() => regexMail.test(mail) != true ? <Text>Mail invalide</Text> : <Text>Mail valide</Text>}
```

Comment: You might want to take a step back and go through a tutorial better. This isn't how you change state, and I'm not sure what's supposed to be in the missing part.

Comment: Also, returning JSX in an event handler doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You cannot directly change the state like this, you need to use setState() instead. Please read this to understand it better: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html. On that website you'll have even more information about how React/React Native works. It seems that you don't get the basics of React (yet)